# Java Teacher Won't let me use any variable other than the ones he says we should

Tags: java, variables

For my AP comp sci class in Java, my teacher gave us a simple lab where we have to find the factors of numbers from 2-100.  We also had to find if a number was prime, perfect, abundant, and/or deficient.  He gave us all the methods we should use and all the variables we should use, those being an array to hold the factors and an int counter to count the number of factors.  This was pretty easy and I finished quickly.  In order to get perfect, abundant, and deficient, I also created a sum variable to add up the factors.  My teacher told me that I couldn't do that because in the real world, I wouldn't be able to.

Two questions:

1. Does this make any sense?  Why wouldn't a developer be able to add variables?
2. Is there a simple way that anyone sees to do this without adding a variable?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In the real world, I create variables all the time.

Comment: Your teacher is lying to you.

Comment: In the real world, variable create you!

Comment: It's hard to tell what he meant without seeing code, unfortunately.

Comment: Did he give you a `sum()` method or something? He might have intended for some kind of recursion.

Comment: Please post your code so we have a better understanding of your teachers instructions.

Answer (score 2):

You could reuse the counter to add the factors, I suppose; however, if you're changing his main to do this, that's something that might not be allowed, I guess. Often you can only change your function and not another.  You may not even have access to their function if you're working on a library.

The number of factors would just be arr.length, so you really don't even need a counter.

Answer (score 2):

1) No. I would argue that, in general, in the "real world," adding variables is *always* good, *if it improves your code's readability*. The two most important things are 1) does your code work correctly and 2) can another programmer understand what you've done easily. The only time adding an extra variable would be "bad" is if you're working in a crazily memory-bound environment (maybe on an embedded device).

2) If you really only have two variables to work with - the list of factors, and the count of factors, then you have to re-use the "factor count" variable to store the sums. Unless you know the exact length of the factors list - then you could test by unrolling the loop (e.g., `if(factors[0] + factors[1] + ... + factors[20] > number)`) - this avoids using a temporary variable.

Answer (score 1):

In response to your first question, variables take up memory.  A simple int variable to hold a sum is a pretty small amount of memory, and when developing for typical applications for desktop machines, memory typically isn't an issue.  But in any instance where you need to make your program as memory efficient as possible, adding variables adds to the memory your program uses.  But this is probably going to be pretty rare...

Comment: In those cases, you're unlikely to be using Java in any case. VMs take more space than compiled code, for sure.

Comment: Android apps are developed with Java, although even phones are starting to get to the point where you have more memory then you'll ever need.  But it memory is still a consideration nonetheless in some scenarios, just not very likely with Java.

Comment: @Joel, what are you on about? Lots of applications are written in Java.

Comment: I think he mostly means for very small embedded systems, in which case I believe he is right - C is probably much more popular than Java for that type of environment.

Comment: What CmdrMoozy said.  If you're worried about the space of a single integer, then Java isn't the right place for you.  I know it's used in lots of places, including smartphones with multi MB of memory.  It's not used much for places that don't fit an OS though -- and yes, I've worked on those types of apps.

Comment: On the whole, I agree with you Joel.  In Java, and especially with an int, memory isn't a consideration.  But on the more general question of "why wouldn't I want to create an extra variable?" memory constraints is the answer.  The point I was trying to make and perhaps the point the teacher may (poorly) be trying to make is that variables are just purely free.  They do cost memory.  But in the specific case of the original question, the limitation seems pretty silly.